# Convert user input data into Data Frame R

Tags: r, data-analysis

To solve a problem, my input data is provided by the user like

```
1,S0006,C000124,12Jan2017,179,7296
2,S0002,C000124,26Feb2017,109,7941
3,S0008,C000124,22Feb2017,190,4511
4,S0006,C000124,03Jan2017,150,7296
5,S0005,C000124,08Feb2017,120,5812
6,S0003,C000124,26Apr2017,46,7512
```

I want to convert this into a data frame.
I dont know how to do this

Comment: Look at `read.csv`?!

Comment: but they are passed at input

Comment: Add sample code that can be tested and solutions verified.

Comment: I am late to this but just stumbled on this question (looking for the cleanest way to read stdin into a data frame). Given the answer you provided, I think the question is missing the part where you are trying to read data from `stdin`, not from a file, is this correct ?

Answer (score 2):

Update :
i got the answer after thinking a lot!.

```
a<- read.csv("/dev/stdin",header=FALSE);
```

Comment: Can't believe how easy this is yet I'm the first upvoter.

Answer (score 0):

If your input data is in csv or txt file, it is automatically will be in data.frame format when reading it with read.csv or read.table functions. You can also use data.frame function to convert matrix or some other formats to data.frame format. Here is a link how you can read different data types: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-data-import-tutorial

If your data is not in file, you need to create by hand, for example:

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,sv = paste0("s000",c(2,8,6,5,3)),cv=rep("c000124",5))

str(df)
```

[image]